# Browser-neutral way to start local process from intranet

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, cross-browser, intranet

We currently have a corporate intranet built with ASP.NET and originally designed for IE.  One of the purposes of the intranet is to manage file versioning and to launch programs with the current file version.  This requires the intranet to start processes on the machine locally, and is done using ActiveX.

We are now reworking the intranet to be as browser-neutral as possible, but this local application launching thing has us stumped.

Can anyone suggest a browser-neutral way to start processes locally?  This is strictly for internal use on a corporate LAN with computers that are authenticated on a Windows domain.

Possibilities that we've floated, in rough order of preference:

- Javascript (doubt it's possible)
- Silverlight
- Flash
- Java applet
- Scheduling a task for "now" with windows group policy (seems like a hack)
- Have a locally-running process and use IPC from a server (also sort of a hack)

Anyone have any thoughts on what is likely to work and be not a huge PITA to implement?

Comment: java applet would work. having process (service) running on your computers is 100% legit way of handling it as well.

Comment: Our main concern with the local process is that we get new computers and/or reinstall Windows with some regularity, and it's hard for us to say with 100% certainty that the computers have everything set up correctly.  The main point of having all of our corporate stuff on an intranet, instead of the whole thing just being a local program, is to avoid installation woes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [signed Java applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) is a pretty easy way to do this. Requires end-user buy-in only once, can be updated at the server side, can have near-total rights to the target machine, etc.

Alternately, you could always write a browser plug-in using the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). A bit more of a pain, actual install required, trickier programming interface, feels a bit 90's, but still possible. :-) NPAPI plug-ins are well-supported across multiple browsers.

Comment: Java applet it is.  In a perfect world the user wouldn't have to buy-in at all (who ever reads those things??), but it's a small price to pay.  We have a prototype signed applet running, and it seems to be pretty straightforward.  Thanks for the help!